# Optional for one entity, optional for another entity: many end optional

Tags: sqlite

Please could you help me in sqlite :

agents may make bookings for performers, and performers may also make bookings for themselves. It is also possible for agents to make bookings for other functions that do not involve performers. An agent may be responsible for making bookings for a number of performers. If a performer is represented by an agent, each performer may have only one agent. The relationship is optional for both entities.

[image]

This relationship can be converted into three relations. There will be one relationship to represent the performers, another for the agents, and a third will store details of the relationship between performers and agents (where such a relationship exists).

Relation: Performers

[image]

Relation: Agents

[image]

Relation: Agent-Performer

[image]

My Question : is it necessary to create third relation ( Agent-Performer) for representing the relationship between the two relations, Performers and Agents?

what is the problem if i put the foreign key in the many end relation(Performer) and put null in some values in foreign key , without creating third relation ( Agent-Performer)?

PLease, help me in that.

Comment: "each performer may have only one agent" is usually not true in reality. Is this homework?